# Почему не работает animate.css (и wow)?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

Не работает animate.css и wow.
Сайт на WordPress. В консоли нет ошибок.
Не работает даже просто animate.css без wow.

Скрипт вроде подключил правильно, в html прописал классы.

Мой код из functions.php :

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mk_enqueue_scripts' );
function mk_enqueue_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/animate.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wow', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/wow.min.js', array(), '', true );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mk_wow_init_in_footer');
function mk_wow_init_in_footer() {
add_action( 'print_footer_scripts', 'wow_init' );
}
function wow_init() {?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    new WOW().init();
    </script>
     <?php }
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что выводит console.log(WOW)?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно при вызове WOW().init(); еще не загрузился сам скрпт. Попробуйте сделать вызов внутри jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) { });

```php
add_action( 'print_footer_scripts', 'wow_init' );
}
function wow_init() {?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
            new WOW().init();
        });
    </script>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: Не помогло,....

Comment: Проблема в  animate.css